# Dev Tool to detect declared jquery Event Twice

Tags: jquery, events, devtools

i am testing this script to use as dev tool; i am detecting events on elements but i need retrieve the name, id of element that have more that 1 declared, attached event listener with jquery, and the function, line, file of script to trace the relation.

```
$(document).each(function() {
    var events = $._data(this, "events");
    for (data in events) {
        console.log(events[data]);
    }
});
```

the main idea is implement it on a layout and not use third party script extension.

Comment: `$._data` is not really meant to be used in a productional environment.  It should be used, if at all, for debugging.  You should be aware of if your application is double binding events before it reaches a productional environment, and fix that issue, rather than writing script to check for it.

Comment: omg @Taplar this script is for dev environment, you read the post??, when you have diferent developer generating javascript files and plugins you need a script to detect this issue and fix.

Comment: Calm down dude.  The last sentence makes it sound like you want to have this baked into the application some how.  And if you have developers that are creating logic that is double binding, rather than having a script to detect that, you need to have a sit down with that deleveloper and explain to them what they are doing wrong, and fix the **real** issue.

Comment: @Taplar of course this will be implemented in the web aplication but only for dev environment of purging Script, becouse it i need show to a developer this data in a good layout to determinate the element mentioned: name tag, id tag, event atached twice, and if posible a trace to the script.